# Accessing a class as a property within another class

Tags: c#

I have created three classes which are related through properties in a `Grandfather.Father.Child` relationship. I am trying to write to a property of `child` class but `Father` class's `get` returns `null` if I am calling the `child` class through the full hierarchy. These are parts of the three classes:

```
namespace ShiftJournal.Library
{
    public class JournalEntry
    {
        public WorkOrder OrderInfo { get; set; } = new WorkOrder();
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public int FinishedQty { get; set; }
    }
    public class WorkOrder
    {
        public ElectronicAssembly Assembly { get; set; } = new ElectronicAssembly();
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
    public class ElectronicAssembly
    {
        public string PartNo { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do (the code returns `null` at `OrderInfo` property:

```
using System;
using ShiftJournal.Library;

namespace ShiftJournal.UI
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JournalEntry entry = new JournalEntry();
            entry.OrderInfo.Assembly.PartNo = @"Something";
        }
    }
}
```

Is what I am trying to achieve here is even possible? Or am I missin something about the use of `class`?

Must I address each `class` separately?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Boris.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly for me once I filled in the closing curly braces. What version of C# are you using? If it compiles, though, it should work.

Comment: I am using C# in VS2017 Community, it should be C# 7.0.

Comment: That's what I used. Worked fine. Can we see a complete, compilable example?

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: Again, it works perfectly for me.

Comment: I get a `null` exception on `OrderInfo`.

Comment: @BorisK. add exception to the question

Comment: [Here's your code in a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xsMjDC). Works fine. It seems likely to me that there's a seemingly unimportant detail that you're doing differently in the code you're running, or something you just didn't notice. My suspicion is that you may be sharing none of your actual code, but only an ad hoc example that you're composing in the editor here, which includes everything *you think* the actual code is doing.

Comment: Not strictly related to the problem, but your names (Grandfather.Father.Child) suggest inheritance, while you are actually using composition (has a vs is a relationship)

Comment: ...or worse, it's stuff that you think ought to be equivalent to everything you think ought to matter. In programming, "ought to be" is very often a dysphemism for "isn't". The answer then is to identify everything that differs between the two.

Comment: @GianPaolo, seems like I've used the wrong terminology, which is misleading. I am trying to achieve exactly what is represented in the code.
@S.Petrosov, `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
ShiftJournal.Library.JournalEntry.OrderInfo.get returned null.`

Comment: @BorisK. I'm voting to close because you won't post the code that raises that exception. The real code either neglects to initialize `OrderInfo`, or else sets it to `null` later. There's no other option. It's not gremlins and it's not a compiler bug. Since you're unwilling to recognize that fact, the question will never be answerable.

Comment: @EdPlunkett. The whole code is in the question. There whole solution contains 2 projects - ConsoleApp (ShiftJournal.UI) and ClassLibrary (ShiftJournal.Library). The classes are in separate files. I haven't got around to adding anything else, so there is no other code to speak of...

Comment: @EdPlunkett. I DO recognize the fact that it couldn't have been gremlins, since I wouldn't have posted a question in that case...Thanks anyway

Comment: I posted a fiddle above. Find the differences between that and your code. One of them is causing the issue.

Comment: @EdPlunkett. Well, I got it to work. I've created a separate instance for each class in the Console App, which in theory should have been created in the class itself. Thanks again!

Comment: @BorisK. I'd love to see the code that actually created the error. I *know* you're not telling me the whole truth. No gray areas here. The code in the fiddle can't fail unless you do something else that breaks it.

Comment: I have finally figured it out. The problem wasn't in the code, but in the type of `Class Library` I have selected for the project. NOW it works as intended.